# I've created a new project by checking the "include kotlin" box in Android Studio 4.1.3 and out of the box I get an error while compiling

Tags: kotlin

I've created a new project by checking the "include kotlin" box in Android Studio 4.1.3 and out of the box I get an error while compiling

Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10.
Required by:
project : > com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5 > com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.2
> No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10 available for offline mode.

Comment: Are you online? Also check Gradle isn't in Offline mode (easiest way to check - pop out the Gradle tab on the right, check the icon that looks like ``-//-`` isn't lit up - click it if it is)